# How to connect to ExchangeServer from ASP.net (using c#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server

This is the code I use to connect to ExchangeServer. My account has 2 mailboxes assigned to it. Could this be the problem? I don't get any bug nor some result. Can someone help me, please?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

    service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( "{Active Directory ID}", "{Password}", "{Domain Name}" );


    service.AutodiscoverUrl("user@domain.com");

    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(
                WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
                new ItemView(10));

    foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not have AutoDiscover set up in Exchange Server. So I had to give the url in the service:

```
service.Url = new Uri("https://mail.domain.com/EWS/exchange.asmx");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you're getting?

EDIT:

Sorry, so you did.

So `findresults` is `null` or has `Count == 0` ?

And what's with the curly braces in your code:

`service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( "{Active Directory ID}", "{Password}", "{Domain Name}" );`

Comment: the curly braces could be for example
Active Directory Id: stohi
Password: pass1234
domain name: domain.com

I did not look to the values of count or findresult

Comment: OK so those arent' the exact arguments you're passing those into your constructor.

How about you try stepping through with the debugger to see if its the connection attempt that is failing or if `service.FindItems` is returning no items. If you're not getting any exceptions the latter seems more likely.

Comment: I just added a counter (integer variable) in the foreach-loop. But it seems like there is no item in findResults.Items. So the foreach-loop will never be accessed.

Comment: Obvious question, but I have to ask - are you sure there are items in the mailbox you are accessing? Can you see them in Outlook?

Comment: yes, of course there are. But I have 2 mailboxes: one is for my account and the second is for IT Helpdesk. So if you understand normally each emailaddress has one mailbox, but I have two mailboxes.

Comment: And your code works if you run this code with an account/email address that has only one mailbox associated with it?

I *think* there are some overridden versions of `FindItems` - sorry can't look yet as am busy doing a release today - but perhaps one of these will do it?